# Google Autocomplete Search bar default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, google-places

I am using Google autocomplete for my map search bar. I have restricted the allowed suggestions to cities in the US.

When someone types in 'asdasd' he will of course get no suggestion.

I was looking through all the available documentation but haven't found what I am looking for.

Is there any way, that a default text can show up when no suggestion is available. Like the dropdown saying: Sorry, nothing matching your search result is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set if syntax for exemple:

```
if (places !=null){
mSuggestionText.setText(your place list);
}
else{
mSuggestionText.setText("Sorry, nothing matching your search result is available.");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a trick...
See my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/a86Ltvyf/)**.

This script checks if suggestion `ul` (the dropdown created by jQuery-UI autocomplete) has class `display:none` 200 ms after a keyup.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var suggestions = [
                    "allo",
                    "bonjour"
                    ];
    $("#myAutocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: suggestions
    });

    $("#myAutocomplete").on("keyup",function() {
        //console.log("typing");
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(( $(".ui-autocomplete").css("display") == "none" ) && ( $("#myAutocomplete").val() != "" )){
                console.log("No result!");
                $("#myAutocompleteMsg").html("Sorry, nothing matching your search result is available.");
            }else{
                $("#myAutocompleteMsg").html("");
            }
        },200);
    });
});
```